# Battery issue in my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, battery

I got an ASUS Fx504. Battery is draining very quickly approx 2 hr maximum with Ubuntu 18.04, while in windows is about 5-6 hr battery. I got dual boot and the TLP doesn't work.

Comment: Please install the recommended Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I got the recommended Nvidia drivers and still the battery issue

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or list the first few contents after running `top` in a terminal? Maybe another process besides the graphics is consuming your resources.

Comment: @PSA here is the screenshot https://ibb.co/MsQbzs4 after running top in the terminal. Could you identify an issue?